# Is there a good and easy paper to code policy gradient algorithms (REINFORCE) from scratch?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, policy-gradients, implementation, reinforce

I am interested in learning about policy gradient algorithms and REINFORCE. Can you suggest a good and easy paper that I can use to code them from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is maybe not a paper but this article is dope.

I got 2 link in below to help you understand about policy gradient algorithms especially Reinforce Learning. Both article have a good explanation about that algorithms and not only an explanation, also contain a good example about that. They really put their effort into it so i'm sure if you've read it and really understand it, you can code from scratch. Hope this is help you.

If you think this answer is helping you, i will grateful if you make my answer as accepted. Just kidding, have a nice day....

(no i'm not kidding)

https://towardsdatascience.com/policy-gradients-in-a-nutshell-8b72f9743c5d by Sanyam Kapoor on Towardsdatascience.com

https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/rl-policy-gradients-explained-9b13b688b146 by Jonathan Hui on Medium.com

Comment: I'm leaving this open b/c you got an upvote (so presumably helpful to the OP.  But could you please excerpt a relevant passage from each article and provide some context?  Otherwise, someone else might come along and delete this answer.